# Validators.email directive not working correctly

Tags: angular

I am using the `Validators.email` directive (https://angular.io/api/forms/EmailValidator) to check that the structure of the email id is correct. However, I notice that it passes `hello.com@com` input. Is this expected behavior? The code example is at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xesgxe

Check `createForm()` function in `signup-component.component.ts`

Comment: Thats correct behavior, email addresses do not always end with .com or a TLD: for example `test@localhost` is a valid email. Here more info on this matter: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As  [enf0rcer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3492940/enf0rcer) said in his comment it is the correct behaviour. But if you are not satisfied with it you can use below code in your `signup-component.component.ts`.

```
export class SignupComponentComponent implements OnInit{

  EMAIL_PATTERN = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

  constructor() {}

  createForm(){
    this.signupForm = this.fb.group({
      email:[null,[Validators.required,Validators.pattern(this.EMAIL_PATTERN)]],
    });
  }
}
```

See the updated [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-c6pbbp?file=src/app/signup-component/signup-component.component.ts).